# weka.core.UnassignedDatasetException when creating an unlabeled instance

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka

I trained an IBK classifier with some training data that I created manually as following:

```
ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<String>();
classVal.add("C1");
classVal.add("C2");
atts.add(new Attribute("a"));
atts.add(new Attribute("b"));
atts.add(new Attribute("c"));
atts.add(new Attribute("d"));
atts.add(new Attribute("@@class@@", classVal));

Instances dataRaw = new Instances("TestInstances", atts, 0);
dataRaw.setClassIndex(dataRaw.numAttributes() - 1);
double[] instanceValue1 = new double[]{3,0,1,0,0};
dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue1));

double[] instanceValue2 = new double[]{2,1,1,0,0};
dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue2));

double[] instanceValue3 = new double[]{2,0,2,0,0};
dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue3));

double[] instanceValue4 = new double[]{1,3,0,0,1};
dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue4));

double[] instanceValue5 = new double[]{0,3,1,0,1};
dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue5));

double[] instanceValue6 = new double[]{0,2,1,1,1};
dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue6));
```

Then I build up the classifier:

```
IBk ibk = new IBk();
try {
    ibk.buildClassifier(dataRaw);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to create a new instance with unlabeled class and classify this instance, I tried the following with no luck.

```
IBk ibk = new IBk();
try {
    ibk.buildClassifier(dataRaw);
    double[] values = new double[]{3,1,0,0,-1};
    DenseInstance newInst = new DenseInstance(1.0,values);
    double classif = ibk.classifyInstance(newInst);
    System.out.println(classif);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I just get the following errors

```
weka.core.UnassignedDatasetException: DenseInstance doesn't have access to a dataset!
at weka.core.AbstractInstance.classAttribute(AbstractInstance.java:98)
at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.classifyInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:74)
at TextCategorizationTest.instancesWithDoubleValues(TextCategorizationTest.java:136)
at TextCategorizationTest.main(TextCategorizationTest.java:33)
```

Looks like I am doing something wrong while creating a new instance. How can I create an unlabeled instance exactly ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
double classif = ibk.classifyInstance(newInst);
```

When you try to classify `newInst`, Weka throws an exception because `newInst` has no Instances object (i.e., dataset) associated with it - thus it does not know anything about its class attribute.

You should first create a new Instances object similar to the dataRaw, add your unlabeled instance to it, set class index, and only then try classifying it, e.g.:

```
Instances dataUnlabeled = new Instances("TestInstances", atts, 0);
dataUnlabeled.add(newInst);
dataUnlabeled.setClassIndex(dataUnlabeled.numAttributes() - 1);        
double classif = ibk.classifyInstance(dataUnlabeled.firstInstance());
```

Comment: bro your answer is hack. I've given answer which is appropriate with respect to weka documentation

Comment: @TaimoorChangaiz why is this answer a hack?

Comment: @k29 because it is not according to documentation. Documentation suggests proper way to do it.

Answer (score 15):

You will see this error, when you classify a new instance which is not associated with a dataset. You have to associate every new instance you create to an [`Instances`](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~ablumer/weka/doc/weka.core.Instances.html#_top_) object using [`setDataset`](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~ablumer/weka/doc/weka.core.Instance.html#setDataset%28weka.core.Instances%29).

```
//Make a place holder Instances
//If you already have access to one, you can skip this step
Instances dataset = new Instances("testdata", attr, 1);
dataset.setClassIndex(classIdx);

DenseInstance newInst = new DenseInstance(1.0,values);

//To associate your instance with Instances object, in this case dataset
newInst.setDataset(dataset);
```

After this you can classify newly created instance.

```
double classif = ibk.classifyInstance(newInst);
```

http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~ablumer/weka/doc/weka.core.Instance.html

[Detailed Implementation Link](https://taimoorchangaizpucitian.wordpress.com/2015/12/03/weka-create-instance-and-training-data-using-arff/)

Comment: This is the best answer because you can use the `Instance` directly instead of using the `Instances.firstInstance()` function. I added a bit more context to the code to make it clear how to use this approach if you need to create a new `Instances`.

Answer (score -1):

See pages 203 - 204 of the WEKA documentation. That helped me a lot! (The Weka Manual is a pdf file that is located in your weka installation folder. Just open the doucmentation.html and it will point you to the pdf manual.)

Copy-pasting some snippets of the code listings of Chapter 17 (Using the WEKA API / Creating datasets in memory) should help you solve the task.

Comment: This is essentially a [link only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), although the link is a reference to the documentation. Please provide some context (i.e. what does it say on pages 203-204) so that if the documentation changes in future, this answer is still helpful

Comment: You are right. The thing is I don't remember anymore. I remember that in the first place my problem was finding the WEKA manual - it wasn't that obvious that it is in the program installation folder (I was searching for it on the website, but maybe its location is made more obvious now). So I thought it might be useful to mention where the manual is. Because before that I was trying to read the javadocs and deal with incomplete code snippets from forums - this never lead to a solution. However, once I found the manual I was able to solve every problem - it is really worth having a look at it.