# "Convert" command line to java code for Weka

Tags: java, weka

I am using this command line

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -T tdata.arff -l rndforrest.model -p 0 > data.out
```

But I want to do it in java without using files, everything should be on the fly. The model can be loaded once at the beginning and the tdata.arff should be one data row for which I need the prediction (classification?).

Like this:

```
weka.classifiers.Classifier rndForrest = (weka.classifiers.Classifier)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("rndforrest.model");
var dataInst = new weka.core.Instance(1, new double[] { 0, 9, -96, 62, 1, 200, 35, 1 });
double pred = rndForrest.classifyInstance(dataInst);
```

I get an error

```
Instance doesn't have access to a dataset!
```

Thank you for help.

edit: my code

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

var values = new double[] { 0, 9, -96, 62, 1, 200, 35, 0 };

weka.classifiers.Classifier rndForrest = (weka.classifiers.Classifier)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("rndforrest.model");
var dataInst = new weka.core.Instance(1, values);

FastVector atts = new FastVector();
for(int i=0; i < values.Length; i++) {
atts.addElement(new weka.core.Attribute("att" + i));
}

weka.core.Instances data = new Instances("MyRelation", atts, 0);
data.add(dataInst);
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
double pred = rndForrest.classifyInstance(data.firstInstance());
Console.WriteLine("prediction is " + pred);
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Pleade do always provide the full stacktrace. Also, this is not a "convert command line to java code" issue, but the way you use an Instance. See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151702/create-an-unlabeled-instance-in-weka

Comment: How do I read the trained model quicker than my way?

Comment: I don't think there is a quicker way, but you can always ask a new question about this.

Comment: It might be facing [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12151702/1222852) which is [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28140720/1222852)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error says it, doesn't it?

> Instances doesn't have access to a dataset!

The Javadoc for the constructor you use says:

> public Instance(double weight, double[] attValues)
>
> Constructor that inititalizes instance variable with given values. Reference to the dataset is set to null. (ie. **the instance doesn't have access to information about the attribute types**)

Every `Instance` has to belong to a data set (`Instances`), because in Weka each value of an instance is stored as a double value. Additional information is needed to determine how to interpret that double value (e.g. as double, string, nominal, ...) and this information is provided through the data set.

You need to do something like:

```
FastVector atts = new FastVector();
// assuming all your eight attributes are numeric
for( int i = 1; i <= 8; i++ ) {
  atts.addElement(new Attribute("att" + i));   // - numeric
}
Instances data = new Instances("MyRelation", atts, 0);

data.add(dataInst);
```

(Also see [Creating an ARFF file](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file) for additional examples on how to create attributes of a certain type)

Comment: Hi thanks that worked :). But it takes about 2700 milli seconds, that is far too much. I need something below 60ms

Comment: What do the 2700 millis include? Is starting the VM included? I mean, executing this program for just one prediction has a lot of overhead. I'd guess that predicting 100 or even 1000 instances that way won't take noticably longer. Maybe you should open a new question for the speed issue and be very specific about what your requirements are.